# blacklisted - mdaemon misconfigured?

Tags: blacklist, mdaemon

I would like to ask how to get off the blacklists such as `gremlin.ru` and `rfc-ignorant.org abuse`. `http://multirbl.valli.org/lookup/79.129.24.240.html`

Is there anything I should setup in mdaemon server, i.e. vote zones (how to do that) etc ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the SMTP host announce to match up to your DNS is one within mdaemon itself. Some other things to do outside of the server include:

- ensuring a proper MX record is defined
- setting up a SPF entry in DNS
- ensuring the IP is not listed as dynamic by ISP

Those are the "main hitters" that will trigger inclusion onto most blacklists.

Comment: Let's not forget the PTR! :-)

Comment: Typically hard to set MX without PTR of something...

Comment: forwarded to my isp for rDNS. I get blacklisted often lately. Network pcs are ok and the same applies for the server. Could all those pending settings I need to take care of, lead to blacklisting that often? thank you.

Comment: rDNS and smtp banner ok now. few things to go. thank you all for the help

Comment: Exactly which item is "zeroed in on" will vary by the listing service. Some focus on only one while its a combination for others.

Comment: Voting zones seem to be the case in order to delist from http://gremlin.ru/drbl/en/ , are vote zones that important?

Comment: It comes down to how many folks are actually utilizing that service. IMHO this one is a "no" since the service is Russian based (where a lot of spammed hide/spam from) and there does not seem to be any others utilizing the mechanism in building their lists.

Comment: ok what about rfc-ignorant.org abuse then?

Comment: There are a few folks that do use rfc-ignorant.org...

Comment: No problem. The whole spam situation is silly and can be very frustrating.